# Can't understand how User flair adds up

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, flair, discussion

This is my user flair badge:

[profile for Trufa on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/745325cdf7504fdb88910bae9e88dbde.png](http://stackexchange.com)

I have 468 rep points in meta.stackoverflow
and 533 rep points in stackoverflow

I don´t understand what is the 760 in the badge.

I guess the answer is really simple but I CANT get it!!

Comment: Now I'm scared... It's showing my reputation!?! . :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've gained quite a bit of rep in the past 24 hours.  I'd peg you around 350 + 400 total rep yesterday.  The flair doesn't update that quick, the images are cached.  You should see it jump up when the cache gets refreshed, probably once a day.

Comment: LOL The right answer would be tat I´m an impatient bastard!! :) Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your /reputation page on each site... http://Meta.Stackoverflow.com/reputation and https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

See if it adds up to that... If it doesn't, I am out of ideas!

Comment: The OP's rep on both sites already adds-up. It's just the global flair that doesn't.